# C++ trying to get function address from a std::function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, std

i'm trying to find the address of a function from a std::function.

The first solution was:

```
size_t getAddress(std::function<void (void)> function) {
    typedef void (fnType)(void);
    fnType ** fnPointer = function.target<fnType *>();
    return (size_t) *fnPointer;
}
```

But that only works for function with (void ()) signature, since i need for function that
signature are (void (Type &)), i tried to do

```
template<typename T>
size_t getAddress(std::function<void (T &)> function) {
    typedef void (fnType)(T &);
    fnType ** fnPointer = function.target<fnType *>();
    return (size_t) *fnPointer;
}
```

And i get "Error - expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Update: Is any way to capture member class address? for class members i'm using:

```
template<typename Clazz, typename Return, typename ...Arguments>
size_t getMemberAddress(std::function<Return (Clazz::*)(Arguments...)> & executor) {
    typedef Return (Clazz::*fnType)(Arguments...);
    fnType ** fnPointer = executor.template target<fnType *>();
    if (fnPointer != nullptr) {
        return (size_t) * fnPointer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update: To capture lambda i'm using

```
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&Function::operator())> {
};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
    typedef ReturnType (*pointer)(Args...);
    typedef std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> function;
};

template <typename Function>
typename function_traits<Function>::function
to_function (Function & lambda) {
    return static_cast<typename function_traits<Function>::function>(lambda);
}

template <typename Lambda>
size_t getAddress(Lambda lambda) {
    auto function = new decltype(to_function(lambda))(to_function(lambda));
    void * func = static_cast<void *>(function);
    return (size_t)func;
}

std::cout << getAddress([] { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;}) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. You might want to include a full example including usage. Something that shows actual failure.

Comment: Aside: you are assuming (on pain of undefined behaviour) that everything in your `std::function`s are function pointers, which isn't very sensible, because if they were, you could use the function pointer type instead, and not have all this trouble.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the `template` keyword when you call target:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
size_t getAddress(std::function<void (T &)> f) {
    typedef void (fnType)(T &);
    fnType ** fnPointer = f.template target<fnType*>();
    return (size_t) *fnPointer;
}

void foo(int& a) {
    a = 0;
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(int&)> f = &foo;
    std::cout << (size_t)&foo << std::endl << getAddress(f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hint:  When you have problems with C++ syntax, I suggest you use `clang++` to compile your code.  If you play around with how your write the code it will *usually* point you in the write direction to fix the error (when it can figure out what you are doing).

I also suggest that you use variadic templates to make your function a bit more general:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
size_t getAddress(std::function<T(U...)> f) {
    typedef T(fnType)(U...);
    fnType ** fnPointer = f.template target<fnType*>();
    return (size_t) *fnPointer;
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using CLang 3.4 :D

Comment: In that case, if you change add `typedef fnType* fnTypeP;` and change your call to target to `target<fnTypeP>`, clang will *tell* you to add in `template` and where.  If you make the parser's job easy enough it can figure out what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Wait, can you simply convert a `std::function` to a function pointer?  Does that work with stateful functions too?  How does that work?

Comment: I'm using function address to store them into a map and able to remove it. You can convert a std::function into a C function pointer.

Comment: No, you can't in all cases.  For example, if I bind the function into a lambda with capture, `target()` will return a null pointer, and the function will segfault.  Use with caution.

Comment: Yes i just tried that and returned null pointer :(. Is possible to capture lambda address, and &Class::function?

Comment: This is nice, but it only works if rtti is enabled

Answer (score 9):

A `std::function` is just an object, albeit disguised as not-an-object.  So, we can take the address of this object, and this is invariant across copies and such.

To get the pointer, we need a bit of casting. Eg given a function `f1`, we can print the implicit pointer by doing:

```
std::cout << "f1: " << *(long *)(char *)&f1 << std::endl;
```

What this does is:

- takes the address of f1. f1 is itself a pointer to the function object, albeit disguised as a primitive

  - so this address is a pointer to the pointer to the function
  - what we want is the underlying pointer to the function
- cast the pointer to pointer into a pointer to char
- thence to a pointer to long
- now, assuming that pointer sizes are `long`s, we can derefernce this pointer to long, and get the underlying address associated with the function object.

Given two `std::function<void()>`s `f1` and `f2`, we can do things like:

```
std::cout << "f1: " << *(long *)(char *)&f1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "f2: " << *(long *)(char *)&f2 << std::endl;

std::function<void()> f1copy = f1;
std::cout << "\nafter copy f1 into f1copy:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "addresses of f1 and f1copy differ: " << &f1 << " " << &f1copy << std::endl;
std::cout << "but underlying pointers identical: " <<
    *(long *)(char *)&f1 << " " << *(long *)(char *)(&f1copy) << std::endl;

std::cout << "\n after assign f2 to f1copy" << std::endl;
f1copy = f2;
std::cout << "now the underlying pointer of f1copy matches f2's:" << std::endl;
std::cout <<
    *(long *)(char *)&f2 << " " << *(long *)(char *)&f1copy << std::endl;
```

Example output:

```
f1: 4439003784
f2: 4439003912

after copy f1 into f1copy:
addresses of f1 and f1copy differ: 0x7fff572ab970 0x7fff572ab910
but underlying pointers identical: 4439003784 4439003784

 after assign f2 to f1copy
now the underlying pointer of f1copy matches f2's:
4439003912 4439003912
```

Comment: it works, thank you! but I must admit that this can be unsafe though, for example if the compiler uses a different implementation, then there might be a chance that the first member is not a pointer but instead just padding or something like that (even though I don't think that this may happen). But still good answer 