# Understand the syntax of typedef of C function callback

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char (*callback)(int *data);
typedef char (callback2)(int *data);
typedef char callback3(int *data);

char fun_a(int *d)
{
    if (*d == 10)
        return 'A';
    else
        return 'B';
}

int main()
{
    int num = 10;
    callback cb_1_a;
    cb_1_a = fun_a;
    std::cout << cb_1_a(&num) << std::endl;

    callback cb_1_b;
    cb_1_b = &fun_a;
    std::cout << cb_1_b(&num) << std::endl;

    callback cb_1_c;
    cb_1_c = &fun_a;
    std::cout << (*cb_1_c)(&num) << std::endl;

    /*
    callback2 cb2;
    cb2 = fun_a;    // wrong

    callback3 cb3;
    cb3 = fun_a;    // wrong
    */

    return 0;
}
```

C++ compiler doesn't complain about the typedef of `callback2` and `callback3`.

Question> What do `typedef char (callback2)(int *data)` and `typedef char (callback3)(int *data)` mean? Is there a use case where I can apply them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first `typedef` defines `callback` as a *pointer* to a function that takes an `int*` argument and returns a `char` value. So, being a pointer, you can assign a value (the address of an appropriate function) to variables of that type, as you do in the case of your `cb_1_a`, `cb_1_b` and `cb_1_c` variables; in the first case (`cb_1_a = fun_a;`), you are using the function's name (but note: *without* the parentheses) in place of using an explicit `&` operator (if you add the parentheses after a function name, then your are *invoking* that function).

Your second and third `typedef` statements define their types as *actual* functions, and you cannot assign a value to a function. Also, as you have nothing other than the name `callback2` inside the first set of parentheses in `typedef char (callback2)(int* data);`, those parentheses are actually redundant, and the type is *equivalent* to that defined in the next line: `typedef char callback3(int* data);`.

However, you *can* use the second two types (indirectly) to declare function pointers, by adding the `*` in the relevant variable declarations, like this:

```cpp
    //...
    callback2 *cb2; // cb2 is now a POINTER to a "callback2" type!
    cb2 = fun_a;    // So this is OK - We assign the ADDRESS of fun_a to the cb2 pointer
    callback3 *cb3; // And the same here...
    cb3 = fun_a;    // ...and here
    //...
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation. Also, you may find this post helpful, in terms of using `typedef` and function pointer syntax: [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295432/10871073)

Answer (score 5):

This is a little easier to understand with `using` syntax. You have 2 using statements here:

```
using A = char (*) (int*);
using B = char (int*);
```

(Note that your 2nd and 3rd examples are equivalent).

`A` is a `function-pointer` type. In particular, objects of this type can be used to store the address of any function that takes an `int*` and returns a `char`:

```
char f(int*);
A a = f;
```

`a` can now be used similarly to `f` as you've shown in your examples.

`B` is a function type, i.e. it declares a function that takes an `int*` and returns a `char`. So this line:

```
B b;
```

is the same as declaring a function `b` like this:

```
char b(int*);
```

There's not really much you can do with this, at least in an evaluated context, as I don't think there's any way to provide a definition for this function declaration.

Comment: I found a use case: [Comparing std::functions for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920804/8705305)