# Evaluating if ( std::function<void()> == function )?

Tags: c++

How can I evaluate given expression (function<void()> == functor).

Code example:

```cpp
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void Foo() { }

int main() {

    function<void()> a;
    // if (a == Foo) -> error
}
```

**Edit:** debugging details, and remove picture.

Comment: No images of errors or code, or otherwise plain text please!

Comment: `std::function` is a type-erasing wrapper around any kind of callable. AFAIK there is no way to check what function it actually wraps. `operator==` can only check if the `std::function` has a callable in it or not, not which one it is.

Comment: IMO this is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please explain what your code should do, then we can provide proper solution which will not require comparing `std::function`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing std::functions for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833453/comparing-stdfunctions-for-equality)

Comment: `it < vec.end()` should be `it != vec.end()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::function::target()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) will retrieve a pointer to the stored callable object.  And that's what you're trying to compare.

You must specify the expected stored type, and `target()` will return `nullptr` if the type does not match.

(This means that if `std::function` holds a function pointer, `target()` will return a pointer-to-a-function-pointer.)

```
auto f = Foo; // This pointer existed in an earlier version of the question

if (*it->target<decltype(f)>() == f) { // Success
```

[See it work in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ade6f1znP)

---

Note that because [functions decay to function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559758/function-to-function-pointer-decay):

```
*it->target< decltype(Foo) >() == Foo
```

**will not work**, because `std::function` can not possibly be holding a **copy** of the function `Foo`.  You would need to *decay* the function, such as:

```
*it->target< std::decay_t<decltype(Foo)> >() == Foo
```

or:

```
*it->target< decltype(&Foo) >() == Foo
```

Comment: I suppose the expected type is `decltype(f)`.

Comment: Spent a couple hours trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: @MSalters  Very good idea.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe as additional note: If `auto f = Foo;` hadn't decayed the type already, it should probably be `std::decay_t<decltype(f)>`, e.g. if `f` was the name of the function instead.

Comment: @user17732522 it should be, yes.  `decltype(Foo)` would fail in this call.

Comment: I would also maybe add that if you don't already know the target type for sure, you will also need to special case for `target()` returning a null pointer. (You mentioned that, but in the code it is not considered.)

Comment: `(*it->target<decltype(&Foo)>() == Foo` also works.  But not `(*it->target<decltype(Foo)>() == Foo`.  Must be that decay behavior not decaying when it has become so taken for granted.