# Find and delete a std::function object from a map of vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, std-function

I am currently trying to implement a messenger system for my game engine. It uses function callbacks of the form:

```
typedef std::function<void(const Message &)> Callback;
```

It maintains a message list:

```
mutable std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Message>> messageList;
```

And a callback dictionary of signature:

```
mutable std::map<std::string, std::vector<Callback>> callbackDictionary;
```

which is used to call all the callbacks 'bound' to a specific message type. When the callback function is called, the respective message is passed. So far so good.

For better understanding, here is the subscribe method that lets the user add a function method that is called for every message of the subscribed to type.

```
void Messenger::Subscribe(Message::Type type, Callback callbackFunction) 
const
{
    callbackDictionary[type].push_back(callbackFunction);
}
```

And here an example of how it used (by the clickable component class)

```
messageBus.Subscribe("Message/Click", [this](const Message & message) {this->OnClick(static_cast<const ClickMessage &>(message)); });
```

Now my problem:

I want to implement an unsubscribe method that finds a function/method in the dictionary's vector and removes it. Note that the function could be subscribed to more than one message type. I was thinking of something like this:

```
void Messenger::UnSubscribe(Callback callbackFunction)
{
    for (auto & pair : callbackDictionary)
    {
        auto & functionList = pair.second;
        for (auto function : functionList)
        {
            if (function == callbackFunction)
                functionList.erase(std::remove(functionList.begin(), functionList.end(), function), functionList.end());
            // I am aware of issues that may appear from looping deleting while looping
        }
    }
}
```

However, the comparison operator (==) appears to be undefined for function objects. I couldn't come up with an easy way to get around this. So any ideas are much apprechiated. I am just trying to avoid some kind of id system cause from experience the can be a chore to manage. Especially when all kinds of functions and members can be added everywhere throughout the program.

Comment: Would a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039824/451600 work?

Comment: when are callbacks considered conceptually equivalent for unsubscribe()'ing ? note that closure objects ( ie. the result of lambda expressions ) have unique types ...

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe even assuming that's what the OP really's looking for, that works only with function pointers and captureless lambdas (or anything you know the type of upfront)...

Comment: Have you considered using [Boost Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?

Comment: I find you are better off using a subscription token.  Also, the number of hooks, how many are subscribed, the frequency all matter.

Comment: If whoever registered a callback object is supposed to keep a copy of it (for unregistering it again) then why don't you store pointers to original instead? Pointers can be easily compared.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Firstly, thanks for your answer. (I know this is not really helpful) but conceptually functions should be equal if they have the same behaviour. So as you have pointed out the issue arises when using [&] lambdas. More precisely: Functions/Lambdas with the same code that modify the same data (whether that be the same reference or this object) are equal. BTW: I have tried pointers to std::function objects and lambdas but they give me weird errors

Comment: @AdrianKoch "callables" do not have a natural equality operation on them in C++.  And `std::function` is a *callable* (well, copyable callables), not whatever you think it is modelling.  Second, your system seems to require a single message to be passed to callbacks (or some kind of dynamic or unsafe casting), which seems suboptimal.  Third, what happens if you have a callback registered, and then the object referred to in the callback has its lifetime end?

Comment: @Yakk The second point is correct but doesn't really present a big issue due to the limited scope of the system (However, if u have a better idea.... I'm open to it). To the third point: any object that subscribes to a message in its constructor shall unsubscribe from that message in its destructor (That's where this whole problem came from ^^)

Comment: @ÖöTiib I am looking at something in the lines of bool foo = true;
 std::function<bool(int, int)> f;
 f = [&](int a, int b) {return foo; };
 std::function<bool(int, int)> * ff = &f;

Comment: @AdrianKoch Follow the rule of 0 as much as possible.  Represent resources you have to clean up as objects, not as tasks you have to remember to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equality operator in std::function.
A rationale can be found in the old `tr1::function` [N1667](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1667.pdf):

> `operator==` is unimplementable for `tr1::function` within the C++ language, because we do not have a reliable way to detect if a given type `T` is *Equality Comparable* without user assistance

Also note that you're passing `std::function<void(const Message &)>` by-value. That means that you also can't just compare their addresses (not that it would've been a good solution, as `std::function` is easily copyable).

**Solution 1:**

Use some user-provided *key* and std::function as the `value` and store them in a `map` instead of a `vector`.

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Callback>> callbackDictionary;
. . .
void Messenger::Subscribe(Message::Type type, const std::string& cbID, Callback cb);

void Messenger::UnSubscribe(const std::string& cbID);
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a `weak_ptr` to keep track of callbacks.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Callback>> callbackDictionary;
. . .
void Messenger::Subscribe(Message::Type type, std::shared_ptr<Callback> cb);
```

No `UnSubscribe` needed at all! You can auto-unsubscribe the callbacks as soon as `weak_ptr` turns `nullptr`. A prerequisite is that the *listener* must keep the callback alive via a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I really like the second option. I fact, I liked it so much that I have used this shared and weak pointer approach in other places as well. One such place is described in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317531/using-shared-ptr-for-unique-ownership-kind-of-is-this-good-practice .The problem now is that I am not quite sure if this is still good programming practice. Thus I would much appreciat if you could have a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` stores invokables that can be copied.  It makes no requirement that its contents are `==` comparible, and lambdas are not `==` compariable.

You can extract the `typeid` of the stored invokable, assume false if they don't match, add in type erasure features that let you store `==` on various types and dispatch when the types are equal, but then you don't support lambdas as lambdas do not support `==`.

If you say "no lambdas", you can do it, or if you say "no lambdas with bound state".  I'll get into that possibility later, but first I'd advise trying this:

```
using std::shared_ptr<void> token;

template<class...Message>
struct broadcaster {
  using listener = std::function<void(Message...)>;
  using splistener = std::shared_ptr<listener>;
  using wplistener = std::weak_ptr<listener>;

  token listen( listener f ) {
    auto sf = std::make_shared<listener>(std::move(f));
    listeners.push_back(sf); // as weak ptr
    return sf; // as token
  }
  std::size_t operator()( Message... message ) const {
    // remove stale targets:
    targets.erase( std::remove_if( begin(targets), end(targets),
      [](auto&& ptr) { return !ptr.lock(); }
    ), end(targets) );
    auto tmp = targets; // copy, for reentrancy
    for (auto wf : tmp) {
      if(auto sf = wf.lock()) {
        sf( message... );
      }
    }
  }
private:
  mutable std::vector<wplistener> targets;
};
```

In the client, keep track of the tokens you are listening to.  When the client object goes away, it is automatically deregistered from every broadcaster it is listening to.  Just use a `std::vector<token>` and stuff your tokens in there.

If you have more complex logic where listening shouldn't be bound to the listeners lifetime, then you have to store said tokens separately.

This assumes that broadcasting happens roughly as often as registration/deregistration does, or moreso.  If broadcasting is extremely rare and registration/deregistration is extremely common (like a million time more common), the weak pointers to listeners can build up.  You can add a test in `listen` to periodically clean stale listeners.

---

Now, we can do a "no lambdas with bound state".  Then we can bind the state separately, type erase the `==` operation there, and bob is your uncle.

```
state( some_state... )
([](some_state&&...){
  return [&](some_args...){
  /* code */
});
```

a construct like the above would let you return a function object that behaves much like a lambda but with a sensible `==` operation on it.

```
template<class F, class...Args>
struct bound_state {
  std::tuple<Args...> state;
  F f;
  friend bool operator==( bound_state const& lhs, bound_state const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.state==rhs.state;
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&...ts){
    return std::apply(f, state)( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
  }
};
template<class...Args>
auto state( Args&&... args ) {
  auto tup = std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  return [tup=std::move(tup)](auto&& f) {
    return bound_state<std::decay_t<decltype(f)>, std::decay_t<Args>...>{
      tup, decltype(f)(f)
    };
  };
}
```

or somesuch.

Next we create a derived type of `std::function`.  When constructed from a type, it stores a type-erased `==` (either into a global or local location) for it (from a pair of `std::function`s).

It overrides `==` to first check if typeid is identical, and if so it invokes the type-erased `==` on the two elements.

```
template<class Sig>
struct func_with_equal : std::function<Sig> {
  using Base = std::function<Sig>;
  using Base::operator();
  using equality = bool( func_with_equal const&, func_with_equal const& );      
  equality* pequal = nullptr;

  template<class F>
  static equality* erase_equality() {
    return [](func_with_equal const& lhs, func_with_equal const&rhs)->bool {
      assert( lhs.target_type() == rhs.target_type() );
      assert( lhs.target_type() == typeid(F) );
      return *lhs.target<F>() == *rhs.target<F>();
    };
  }
  // on construction, store `erase_equality<F>()` into `pequal`.

  friend bool operator==( func_with_equal const& lhs, func_with_equal const& rhs ) {
    if (!lhs && !rhs) return true;
    if (!lhs || !rhs) return false;
    if (lhs.target_type() != rhs.target_type()) return false;
    return lhs.pequal( lhs, rhs );
  }
};
```

this is half done, but I hope you get the idea.  It is complex and convoluted and forces extra work at every point you register a callback.