# Using shared_ptr for unique ownership (kind of) - is this good practice?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, software-design

this is quite hard to explain but I'll try my best. So, I have a RenderComponent, EventManager and RenderSystem. In my RenderComponents constructor, I raise a renderComponentCreated event which the RenderSystem subscribes to. Using an event args object, I pass a RenderNode as data which contains the information the renderSystem needs to draw the thing (drawable, position and type).

So far so good. Now, when the renderComponent is deleted, I want the RenderNode to be removed from the RenderSystem automatically while still leaving the option to remove it manually e.g. as a reaction to some event. This could be done using a RenderComponentRemoveNodeEvent which again the RenderSystem subscribes to.

Now the 'problem'. From my understanding (and from what I want) the renderNode should be something uniquely owned by the RenderComponent (hence unique_ptr). However, this would require me to either copy (and implement a comparison operator for the renderNode --> to be able to find it when I want to remove it) or pass a reference / raw pointer to the renderNode. However, (If I'm correct) there is no way to know whether a reference still refers to a valid object which would mean that automatic removal could not be implemented.

My solution was to make the RenderNode (that is uniquely owned by the RenderComponent) shared and pass weak pointers to the event. The RenderSystem also now maintains a list of weak pointers that it checks for whether they are still pointing to a valid object and automatically removes them if not. So essentially what I would have wanted is creating a weak pointer from a unique one. However, the way it is now, someone could just create a shared pointer from the weak pointer and keep the RenderNode alive longer than it should. Since the managed object itself (RenderNode) contains references to other objects that will not exist longer than the RenderComponent this may cause serious issues.

My question now: can this be considered good design or have I missed something?

PS: Sorry if this explanation reads a bit clunky (English is not my native) and thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this for a game?

Comment: @arynaq yeah game engine^^

Comment: A possible solution (which is used in many game engines) is to have a "map" using ObjectIDs (via which you can retrieve and reference components owned by other systems), this way you don't have to pass a "full" reference (and ObjectIDs are safe to store)

Comment: @UnholySheep True, I have used this for the components and entities (managed by the entity manager). The problem here is that the RenderNode is owned by the RenderComponent which itself is owned by the entity which is owned by the entity manager. So to do just that (using a map), I would have to use the entity manager to find the entity, component, and node to see whether the entity still exists to then remove it.

Comment: So the entity manager might try to remove an entity that doesn't exist? What kind of manager doesn't know that in the first place? It could just have an entity map, and you can keep a back-pointer to the owning component in the entity.

Comment: @Useless No, the entity manager owns the entities and therefore knows whether they exist. The point is that it ONLY manages the entities and not their components and the nodes of these components. Hence, I would have to give each entity and each component a unique ID to then check whether that component still exists (in the renderSystem) to then be able to delete the respective node if 'its' entity has been deleted. This would work fine with one important caveat: The RenderSystem could only handle one entities and their RenderNodes - not renderNodes in general....

Comment: OK, you have multiple components with very particular semantics, and as far as I can see you haven't described any of them usefully in the question (eg. you mention an EventManager, but never refer to it again, and don't say what interactions it has). Hopefully someone familiar with game engines will be able to guess the details.

Comment: @Useless I have tried to describe the context as briefly as possible since the question is a more general one. I am basically asking for the correct way to reference objects uniquely owned by some other object. And not just reference them but also store these 'references' in a container. I am sorry if that isn't clear from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's certainly nothing wrong with using `std::weak_ptr` to grant access to an object that might be destroyed, that's what it was invented for. But it does necessitate that the object itself be held by a `std::shared_ptr`. Not only does this mask your intent to have the object lifetime controlled by its parent, it forces dynamic allocation of the object and precludes it from being a member variable of the parent.

An alternate approach is to keep track of the pointer through a handle, and have a handle manager that tracks whether the object is alive or dead. The safest way to implement this is to make the manager a base class of the object you're tracking, that way RAII ensures it is always up to date. Here's a sample implementation of that concept. Note: untested.

```
template<class Derived>
class HandleBased
{
public:
    typedef uint64_t handle_t;

    HandleBased() : m_Handle(NextHandle())
    {
        Map()[m_Handle] = this;
    }

    ~HandleBased()
    {
        auto it = Map().find(m_Handle);
        Map().erase(it);
    }

    handle_t ThisHandle()
    {
        return m_Handle;
    }

    static Derived* FindPtr(handle_t h)
    {
        auto it = Map().find(h);
        if (it == Map().end())
            return null_ptr;
        return static_cast<Derived*>(it->second);
    }

private:
    static handle_t NextHandle()
    {
        static handle_t next = 0;
        return next++;
    }

    static std::unordered_map<handle_t, HandleBased*>& Map()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<handle_t, HandleBased*> the_map;
        return the_map;
    }

    handle_t m_Handle;
};
```

And here's an example of how you'd use it:

```
class RenderNode : public HandleBased<RenderNode>
{
};

class RenderComponent
{
    std::unique_ptr<RenderNode> node1;
    RenderNode node2;

public:
    void Setup(RenderSystem& rs)
    {
        node1 = new RenderNode;
        rs.nodes.push_back(node1->ThisHandle());
        rs.nodes.push_back(node2.ThisHandle());
    }
};

class RenderSystem
{
public:
    std::list<RenderNode::Handle> nodes;

    void DoRender()
    {
        for (auto it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); )
        {
            RenderNode* p = RenderNode::FindPtr(*it);
            if (p == NULL)
                it = nodes.erase(it);
            else
            {
                p->DoSomething();
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
};
```