# VS 2017 crashes when compiling template implementation

Tags: c++11, templates, visual-studio-2017, inline

To make it short visual studio 2017 crashes when I am compiling this file:

```
#pragma once

/// @file
/// @brief Class mbe::HandleBase

#include <unordered_map>
//#include <cassert>

namespace mbe
{
    template <class Derived>
    class HandleBased abstract
    {
    public:
        typedef unsigned long long int HandleID;

    public:
        HandleBased();
        ~HandleBased();

        // Maybe rename to GetHandleId()?
        HandleID ThisHandleId();
        /*{
            return id;
        }*/

        // Maybe rename to FindHandledObject
        static Derived * FindPtr(HandleID id)
        {
            auto it = HandleBased::GetMap().find(id);
            if (it == HandleBased::GetMap().end())
                return nullptr;

            // Should always be save
            //assert(dynamic_cast<Derived *>(it->second));
            return static_cast<Derived *>(it->second);
        }

    private:
        static HandleID NextHandle()
        {
            // Every handle will get its own unique id
            static HandleID next = 0;
            return next++;
        }

        static std::unordered_map<HandleID, HandleBased *>& GetMap()
        {
            // Create the static map which will be used to keep track of the Derived handles and their ids
            static std::unordered_map<HandleID, HandleBased *> map;
            return map;
        }

    private:
        HandleID id; // The id of this handle object
    };

#pragma region Template Implementation

    template<class Derived>
    HandleBased<Derived>::HandleBased() :
        id(NextHandle())
    {
        HandleBased::GetMap()[id] = this;
    }

    template<class Derived>
    HandleBased<Derived>::~HandleBased()
    {
        auto it = HandleBased::GetMap().find(id);
        HandleBased::GetMap().erase(it);
    }

    template<class Derived>
    inline HandleID HandleBased<Derived>::ThisHandleId()
    {
        return id;
    }

#pragma endregion

} // namespace mbe
```

It compiles fine when the `ThisHandleId()` function is defined directly below its definition. Is something wrong with my template implementation? I have noticed that the HandleID typedef does not show up in intellisense.

Sometimes VS crashes completely (goes grey and windows displays the message: "Visual Studio 2017 stopped working". Sometimes it just shows that ingame message: "C/C++ optimising compiler stopped working"

[image]

Furthermore, I get a ton of compile errors when defining the other functions beneath the HandleBase class or in an inline file. As I said, everything compiles just fine if all functions are implemented just beneath their definition. I have also experimented with removing inline which avoids the crash but gives me even more compile errors. Mosty complete non-sense such as:

---

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(75): warning C4346: "ThisHandleId": Abhängiger Name ist kein Typ

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(76): note: Präfix mit "typename" zum Angeben eines Typs

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(76): error C2988: Unerkannte Vorlagendeklaration/-definition

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(76): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ""

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(76): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "{"

2>c:\users\adrian\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mars base engine ecs 5\mars base engine ecs\handlebase.h(76): error C2447: "{": Funktionsheader fehlt - Parameterliste im alten Stil?

---

Sorry for the German comments, but u can probably guess what some of them meen. There is stuff like 'depended name is not a type', 'syntax error ""' and 'missing an ; before {'

Also, I don't think removing the inline is a good idea in the first place.

In case you are wondering what the code is for, its described in the acceted answer of this stack overflow question: [Using shared_ptr for unique ownership (kind of) - is this good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317531/using-shared-ptr-for-unique-ownership-kind-of-is-this-good-practice)

Hope you can help me with this weird occurence....

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: @drescherjm Well with crash I mean that vs goes grey and crashes. And windows displayes the message: "Visual Studio 2017 stopped working..." Interestingly, sometimes it doesn't crash completely but instead displays the message: Optimising compiler stopped working. If added it to the post

Comment: Long shot, but would removing the `#pragma region` help?

Comment: @Angew Just tried it, unfortuanately no ^^

Comment: Unrelated to the Q, but are you aware of the fact that `HandleBased<Type1>` and `HandleBased<Type2>` will each have their own `map`? There seems little need to type the vlaue of `map` to anything other than `Derived*`.

Comment: @Angew No I wasn't - ur right! (feeling slightly retarded now ^^) But thanks

Comment: @Angew Wait, I was a little too fast there. Yes, I fact there is a new map generated for each type. But so are the keys. They start from zero for each new Derived. Hence, using the same map would lead to crashes.

Comment: That's true. I was more looking at the map's value type: it would make more sense to me for that to be `Derived*`, since that's what you're actually storing in it. The cast would move from the getter (where it has to happen on each access) to the constructor (where it just happens once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HandleID` is a scoped type. Hence, you will need to use `HandleBased<Derived>::HandleID`. Furthermore, since `HandleID` is a dependent type. Hence, you will need to use `typename HandleBased<Derived>::HandleID`.

Use:

```
template<class Derived>
inline typename HandleBased<Derived>::HandleID HandleBased<Derived>::ThisHandleId()
{
    return id;
}
```

Alternatively, use trailing return type (Thanks are due to @Angew):

```
template <class Derived>
auto HandleBase<Derived>::ThisHandleId() -> HandleId
{
   return id;
}
```

That works since trailing return types are within the scope of the class.

Comment: Alternatively, `template <class Derived> auto HandleBase<Derived>::ThisHandleId() -> HandleId`. Trailing return types are within the scope of the class.