# identify Lambda via reference

Tags: c++, unit-testing, lambda

I want to test a classes function, that just takes a std::function as argument and passes it to another class. In my test, it is passed to a mocked object.

In my test file I create a lambda and give it to the function to be tested.

My question is now, how can I check, if the lambda I receive in my mocked object is still the same like I gave in. Is there a way?

Comment: You could create a mock class that prints on copy and create a lambda that captures an object of that class by value. If it is not the same lambda, it means that your object would have been copied thus it will have printed.

Comment: thats a good idea. but still, is it not possible to locate a lambda? 
I wonder why it is not possible to create a lambda on heap, save a pointer to it, let std::function refer to it and later on check if it is still the same pointer?

Comment: because with your solution, @Light, i cannot be sure, that the testing function dont pass an other std::function to my mock. it wouldn't be copied then and but it is a completly different function.

Comment: I want to check in a very safe way that original lambda is passed. not nested in another one with same return type and arguments or something like this

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding what you're saying by "a other function std::function", if it's another one, then you know it because it does not do the same thing as the function you gave. You just have to call it in the mock object

Comment: ok but it can be possible, that the function to be tested creates a new std::function with a lambda with same arguments and return types and call intern the original one.  then when the mock calls the function with the "right" arguments which it should create, it could be, that the new function gave other arguments to the original nested function . do you understand or shell I make a code example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about check the `typeid`?

---

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iomanip>

std::function<void()> foo(std::function<void()> x){
    return x;
}

std::function<void()> bar(std::function<void()>){
    return []{};
}

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    auto l = [x](){return x;};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (foo(l).target_type()==typeid(l)) <<' ';
    std::cout << (bar(l).target_type()==typeid(l));
}
```

Comment: @MagicMaik `hash_code` may collision while `type_info::operator==` do it right, why you suggest it?

Comment: have you read @Adrians answer ? in en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid it is said that type_info may be not the same for the same object.

Comment: referring to the above link: const std::type_info& ti1 = typeid(A);
const std::type_info& ti2 = typeid(A);
 
assert(&ti1 == &ti2); // not guaranteed
assert(ti1.hash_code() == ti2.hash_code()); // guaranteed

Comment: @MagicMaik the `type_info` **instance** my be different (which makes the address different), but [type_info::operator==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) *Checks if the objects **refer to** the same types.*

Comment: sure , got it :-) I see that this works well. but with hash_code it would work as well as without, wouldn't it ? what should collision ?

Comment: [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) can collision. [type_info::hash_code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) create a hash value, so it can collision.

Comment: btw, don't forget to include `<typeinfo>` if you use `typeid`

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand the problem is that u can't check whether the `std::function` object is still the same. Unfortunately there is no easy way of doing so.

There is no equality operator in std::function. A rationale can be found in the old `tr1::function` N1667:

> `operator==` is unimplementable for `tr1::function` within the C++ language, because we do not have a reliable way to detect if a given type T is Equality Comparable without user assistance

One way (that you will already be aware of), is to pass the function object by reference and compare the addresses. This is not a good solution since function objects are easily copyable.

Another solution would be to wrap the function object in another object that stores the function and assigns an id to it.

Something in the lines of:
[Using shared_ptr for unique ownership (kind of) - is this good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317531/using-shared-ptr-for-unique-ownership-kind-of-is-this-good-practice)

Your 'wrapper object' could inherit from HandleBased and `std::function`. This would allow you to simply compare the keys.

Hope I could help...

Comment: I already thought about your solution, making  a new object that stores the std::function. but It is not so nice in my opinion. I know that std::function can't be compared. but isn't it so, that the std::function just stores the lambda. is there no way to include the lambda in the whole problem ?

Comment: Well, as far as I am aware lambdas are implemented as a small class that overloads the () operator. But lambdas itself just like functions don't implement the == operator. However, apple apples solution of using c++11 RTTI might help out there. Also note: There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.

Comment: so I need to call "hash_code()" from the type_info object in apple apples solution to be safe. Seems that this would be the solution , isn't it?

Comment: Yeah typeid(a).hash_code() == typeid(b).hash_code() would always return true if a and b are the same type. (I have not tested this with lambdas but since they're 'simple' closures It should work) For more info you might want to have a look at std docu http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: @MagicMaik Any progess?